# dexInprocess in gradle not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use "dexInProcess = true" in my gradle build file as following :

```
android {
     dexOptions {
    dexInProcess = true
    }
}
```

But , I am getting the following error :

```
Error:(35, 0) No such property: dexInProcess for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions_Decorated
```

Comment: Is this for android studio 2 ?

Comment: No, I am still using android 1.5

Answer (score 3):

update your build tools to `Build Tools 23.0.2+`

i believe you need the following true to see this command:

```
Gradle 2.4+
Plugin 2.0.0+
Build Tools 23.0.2+
```

can you confirm ? and yes you need the latest build tools. 
Its  not enabled by default in Android studio 2.0 so you need to set it to true as you are doing.

Comment: does this only work with the latest build tools version ? I am currently not able to move to the latest build version due to some old library dependencies

Comment: @r7v Yes, you need `Build Tools 23.0.2+`

Comment: Didn't work for me until I updated Plugin to version 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

this option is no longer supported, you need to comment out it.
like this:

```
        //  dexInProcess = true
```

Comment: in the release notes i dont see that its no longer supported in beta gradle plugin. Can you confirm?  i see the following:  2.0.0-alpha9 (2016/1/30)

Instant Run 
Switched Lollipop and Marshmallow to use native multidex as split apk had installation errors with dex2oat.
Disable dexInProcess by default unless 
android {
dexOptions {
dexInProcess = true
}
}
     from the release notes: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system